# TCP Event Monitor in .NET

Tags: .net, events, tcp, tcplistener

I have a SysTray application that needs to know when a browser runs into an Internet TImeout/Connection Not Found/etc... error.  At the port level, this could be anything from network is unusable to network not found, etc...

I do NOT need to see every TCP packet flowing across the network but I do need to know about TCP/Port/WinSock (whichever works) events flowing across all ports.

Ideally, I would avoid WinPCAP as this is a distributable software product and people tend to dislike WinPCAP on their computers.

I am using .NET 4.0 Full - can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What if a program other than a browser sees the same problems? Do you want to know then?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in seeing the actual TCP packets but only interested in the open connections why not use `NETSTAT -a`?

It will provide you with the protocol, local, foreign and state information of the current connections on your clients computer.

Use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to spawn `NETSTAT -a`. Redirect the output using [`Process.StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) to your application and then filter out the necessary strings with `regex` or `string.split`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response - it led me to IPGlobalPrperties - http://www.eggheadcafe.com/sample-code/csharp.NET/c51bd463-c6c3-48fb-a972-5b440215992a/provides-information-about-the-transmission-control-protocol-tcp-connections-on-the-local-computer.aspx

Using a derivative of that code, I was able to set up a monitor for TCP events.

Comment: That Link is dead.  Could you please update and/or share at least some of your code?  I'm needing to monitor TCP traffic from my co's legacy PBX (via a known IP Address and Port #) to its legacy client software (Oaisys NetPhone v4.6) both no longer supported (unless we upgrade which we won't any time soon) to extract Caller ID phone #'s to work around the client sfw no longer logging Caller ID #'s under Windows 10 (vs. 7 or XP).